# How to put the sorted indexes of an unsorted array into a new array

Tags: c++, arrays, list, sorting, indexing

if i have an array such as `array = {7, 4, 5, 8, 22}` and I want to find the sorted indices of the array such that `sortedIndicies = {2, 0, 1, 3, 4}`, how would I go about doing that? I'm fairly new to coding, and I've been attempting just using for loops and if statements. I tried creating a copy of the original array, bubble sorting the new array, then comparing values in the new sorted array to the original array and using those indices but then i ran into problems if the code had multiple of the same element in the array. Any suggestions? (in a way using fors and ifs that I can understand preferably.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be worth to see your attempts on this one.

Comment: As mentioned below, the sorted indices are S[] = {1,2,0,3,4}. A simple usage would be sorted_array[i] = array[S[i]]. The ranks would be R[] = {2,0,1,3,4} as posted in the question. A simple usage would be sorted_array[R[i]] = array[i]. You can convert S[] to R[] by using R[S[i]] = i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the sorted indices were `{1,2,0,3,4}`

By using only for and if you can do it like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arraySize = 5;

    int arr[arraySize] = { 7, 4, 5, 8, 22 };

    int arrtemp[arraySize] = { 0 };

    int temp;

    int sortedIndices[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        arrtemp[i] = arr[i];               //making a copy of the original array
    }

    //Bubble sorting
    //Sorting the copied array
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arraySize - 1; j++) {
            if (arrtemp[j] > arrtemp[i]) {
                //swap them
                temp = arrtemp[i];
                arrtemp[i] = arrtemp[j];
                arrtemp[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //tracking the location of the sorted values
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
            if (arrtemp[i] == arr[j]) {
                sortedIndices[i] = j;
            }
        }

    cout << "Original Array\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Sorted array\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        cout << arrtemp[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout<<"Sorted indices are\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        cout << sortedIndices[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

> Output:
>
> Original Array
>
> 7 4 5 8 22
>
> Sorted array
>
> 4 5 7 8 22
>
> Sorted indices are
>
> 1 2 0 3 4

Comment: I hope it will help.

Comment: It is not generic but you can make it with  little effort.

Comment: You really don't need to copy the original array. You can sort the indices array directly. [Here is your code with all the extra wasteful work removed.](http://ideone.com/M5Q99a)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried this earlier but i ran into a problem if there would is multiple of the same value in `int arr[arraySize]= { 7, 4, 5, 8, 22 };`, for example, `int arr[arraySize]= { 7, 4, 4, 8, 22 };` would incur a logic error.

Comment: Yes it would be but you can place a check for it.

Comment: @DonnieB: or you could sort the indices array directly and forget about the buggy step of trying to recover the indices after the sort. Click the text link in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks. @Blastfurnace

Comment: @DonnieB: The key idea here is that the sorting algorithm isn't very important. You just need that extra indirection when you compare values. The other answer does the same thing but faster and using the standard library.

Answer (score 4):

the possible solution is to create an array of pairs {value, index}, sort them by value (use `std::pair` which already has appropriate `operator <`) and read indexes from sorted array. It should be easy to write.

Another solution is to create an array of indexes and sort them using values from the first array. In c++11 it may look like this:

```
template<class T>
std::vector<size_t> get_sorted_indexes(std::vector<T> const &array)
{
    std::vector<size_t> indexes(array.size());
    std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0);
    std::sort(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), [&array](size_t l_idx, size_t r_idx)
    {
        return array[l_idx] < array[r_idx];
    });
    return indexes;
}
```

[iota](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) is used to fiil an indexes vector. Indexes is compared by values from the original array `[l_idx] < array[r_idx]`

Yes. It isn't "fors and ifs" solution. But you don't need them. Just use the `sort` function the way you need